# google opensearch plugin ajax drop down

Tags: ajax, search-engine

I am making an opensearch plugin to be used as a search engine provider in the browser.
http://library.curtin.edu.au/services/toolbar/#searchPlugin

As there is no way to specify any ajax call in the xml file,

How do I make a drop down box populated with search suggestions?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firefox supports extensions on the OpenSearch Search Engine Plugin format including the ability to indicating a type of application/x-suggestions+json which is used to specify the URL to use for fetching search suggestions.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/creating_opensearch_plugins_for_firefox.

For lots of examples see http://mycroft.mozdev.org/index.html.